# Firebase FCM API - unable to send WebPush object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am attempting to set our website up to send web and mobile notifications using Firebase FCM.

```
{
    "data":{
        "url":"https://www.google.com"
    },
    "webpush":{
        "data":{
            "title":"yey"
        },
        "notification":{
            "title":"Web Title",
            "body":"Web Body",
            "icon":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Stack_Overflow_logo.svg/250px-Stack_Overflow_logo.svg.png"
        }
    },
    "notification":{
        "title":"Some Title",
        "body":"Test Message 1"
    },
    "token":"a_token_here"
}
```

When sending a message to a website token with a "notification" specified, this gets output by the browser, however, the "data" object does nothing suggesting it doesn't get picked up by my service worker (sw), which handles the url.

If I remove the "notification" object, it gets to my sw, however, the sw does not output anything from the `webpush.notification` object (i.e not title or body or icon). It will, however, use my icon and title specified in the sw. It also receives the base level "data" object, but not the `webpush.data` object.

To me the documentation suggests that information placed in "webpush" should override the base level objects, however, this is not happening.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#WebpushNotification

Current workaround would be to stick everything into the base level "data" object which can be accessed by the sw payload and used to output information, but this doesn't seem to be what the API intends.

Service worker:

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    const title = 'A Title';
    const options = {
        body: payload.data.body,
        icon: 'https://example.com/images/company_logo.png'
    };
    const url = payload.data.url;

    self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
        event.notification.close();
        event.waitUntil(self.clients.openWindow(url));
    });

   console.log(payload);
   return self.registration.showNotification(title, options);
});
```

As above, the sw does receive messages and they are being output to the console if I do not specify a base level "notification" object. However, I do not receive the notification or data from "webpush".

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) page of the FCM documentation they outline the different types of messages along with the differences in how they are handled and displayed by FCM.

Your workaround suggestion of passing all parameters within the data object is perfectly acceptable and is a concept included in the protocol as a recognised alternative to using the predefined fields.

I use this method for all my projects involving push. It allows you to do all your notification customisation on the fly, and given the fields for notifications still aren't fully finalised it future proofs your service workers a little as none of your fields are hard coded.